# Find all div id's, which starts and ends with a specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use jquery to select all div id's that start with 'starting' + 'some random number' + 'ending'

example

```
<div id="starting456ending"></div>
<div id="starting234ending"></div>
<div id="starting789ending"></div>
```

Is it possible to select all with one query?
in a sense $('#+"starting"+"random number selector" + "ending"') ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes there are [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [attribute ends with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

The script would be like below.

```
$('div[id^="starting"][id$="ending"]')
```

---

below is a visual sample

```js
$('div[id^="starting"][id$="ending"]').css('background-color','yellow');
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="startingending"></div>  <!-- select this -->
<div id="starting789ending"></div> <!-- select this -->
<div id="starting789"></div> 
<div id="starting789ending"></div> <!-- select this -->
<div id="789ending"></div>
<div id="starting789ending"></div> <!-- select this -->
```